# SEO + ajax веб-сайт какие есть подходы?

Tags: html, ajax, seo, content

Вообщем есть веб-сайт - интернет магазин, в текущей реализации, при входе статика: хедр и футер. Все остальное подгружается после аяксом(урлы на хистори), сейчас я начал думать над индексацией, какие есть варианты?

Проверять юзер агента, в случае с ботом отдавать статику?

Проверять на наличие JS чем то вроде:

```html
<noscript>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.site.com/disablejs/" />
</noscript>
```

который после в будущем будет отдавать ему только статику

Comment: http://help.yandex.ru/webmaster/robot-workings/ajax-indexing.xml

Comment: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/174992?hl=ru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

help.yandex.ru/webmaster/robot-workings/ajax-indexing.xml

support.google.com/webmasters/answer/174992?hl=ru

Ответ нашелся сразу, можете минусовать ;)